# Converting c++ switch with if statement to Sql

Tags: c++, sql

I wrote a bunch of code in c++ to check for a multiple conditions and also I make use of case. Now am struggling to convert it sql case. Below is the c++ code

```
Switch(TypeEmp){
  case 0:
       if(Age < 65){
           if((income >=0) || (income <=1880000)){
               amnt= income * 52 ;
           }else if(other condition){
               calculate it amnt;
           }
        }
   break;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean convert it to SQL?  C++ and SQL behave differently.

Comment: Ate you trying to do non-database stuff with SQL?

Comment: U can't judge someone without knowing their intention. I want to convert my c++ code so that I can use on sql statement (store procedure).

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like this

```
 select ...
        case
          when (Age < 65) then
            case 
              when (Income >= 0) or (Income <= 1880000) then
                income * 52 
              when (other condition) then
                --TODO: compute other condition amount - "calculate it amnt"
              else
                --TODO: compute amount here 
            end  
          else
            --TODO: return right value here
        end as amnt
        ...
   from MyTable(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be something like

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN AGE < 65 THEN
           CASE
             WHEN INCOME >= 0 OR INCOME <= 1880000 THEN
               INCOME * 52
           ELSE
               CALCULATE_IT_AMNT
           END
         ELSE
           NULL
       END AS SOME_VALUE
  FROM SOME_TABLE
```

This presumes that SOME_TABLE contains the AGE and INCOME columns used in the calculation.